# why my bash function does not work in Jenkinsfil

Tags: docker, jenkins, kubernetes, continuous-integration, jenkins-pipeline

I write this function

```
def docker_images(image_name,image_tag){

def curl_image_exists_status_code =

    curl_image_exists_status_code=sh (
    script:""" docker login -u XXXXX -p $$$$$$  2> /dev/null 1>/dev/null
    docker pull XXXXX/'${image_name}':'${image_tag}' > /dev/null && echo "success" || echo 'failed' 
    """,  returnStdout: true)
    echo "${curl_image_exists_status_code}"
    return (curl_image_exists_status_code == 'success')?true: false
    }
```

but the output is

> success
>
> null

and the last line returns `false`
the output of `curl_image_exists_status_code` should be success and the last line should return true
but why it is not working?

Comment: Where are you printing the return of `docker_images` to stdout? I do not see where `null` would be printed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
def docker_images(image_name,image_tag){

def curl_image_exists_status_code=sh (
    script:""" docker login -u XXXXX -p $$$$$$  2> /dev/null 1>/dev/null
    docker pull XXXXX/'${image_name}':'${image_tag}' > /dev/null && echo "success" || echo 'failed' 
    """,  returnStdout: true)
    echo "${curl_image_exists_status_code}"
    return (curl_image_exists_status_code == 'success')?true: false
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add .trim() to the output of your sh to be as follow:

```
def docker_images(image_name,image_tag){

   def curl_image_exists_status_code =

      curl_image_exists_status_code=sh (
      script:""" docker login -u XXXXX -p $$$$$$  2> /dev/null 1>/dev/null
      docker pull XXXXX/'${image_name}':'${image_tag}' > /dev/null && echo "success" || echo 'failed' 
    """,  returnStdout: true).trim() //this will make your output trimmed
      echo "${curl_image_exists_status_code}"
      return (curl_image_exists_status_code == 'success')?true: false
    }
```

Comment: Trimming is basically removing any white spaces and enters before and after a word or sentence. This will make something like "      hello world      " to "hello world", or "    hi     man  " to "hi     man". So it removes spaces before and after and not in between